# Can I run a script when a MS Teams call is made?

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I'm working from home, and perform certain tasks when a Teams call is made, such as muting the music on my sonos system. I'd like to do some automation on this. Is there a way to run a script (python or js comes to mind) or webhook when the MS Teams app receives a call? Both incoming and outgoing would be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the docs on [Policy Recording](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-recording-policy).  If you make your user subject to a recording policy, then you can create a bot that will get a call whenever that user joins a call (incoming or outgoing).  You don't actually have to accept/record the call, but it'll at least get you the event.  It's probably overkill, but it does at least trigger something.

Comment: Ah, I think you misunderstand. I’m not an admin. I just happen to be using teams while developing entirely non-microsoft software.

Comment: In that case, you're out of luck as far as I know :)  There's a potential for a client-level API down the line, but nothing released yet.